# DeviceIOControl returns Error 87 when trying to read from HID

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to change keyboard LED's color by trying to read and write to HID. So far the write method works fine and I have been able to change keyboard colors successfully however whenever I try to read from it to get the device status, it throws Error Code 87 and DeviceIOControl method returns false. I am actually using methods of Kernel32.dll through PInvoke and this code works fine for both read and write in C++ but I can't seem to read it in C#.

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
             string lpFileName,
             uint dwDesiredAccess,
             uint dwShareMode,
             IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
             uint dwCreationDisposition,
       uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
             IntPtr hTemplateFile
         );

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
               SafeFileHandle hDevice,
               uint IoControlCode,
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)]
               [In] object InBuffer,
               uint nInBufferSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)]
        [Out] object OutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize,
        ref uint pBytesReturned,
        [In] IntPtr Overlapped
);

public void initialize(){
 devHandle = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (devHandle == null) {
                        isInitialized = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    isInitialized = true;
                    return true;

}

public void deviceStatus()
    {
        uint writtenByteLength = 0;
        byte[] Buffer = { 0x02, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

        bool write = DeviceIoControl(devHandle, 0xb0195, Buffer, (uint)Buffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref writtenByteLength, IntPtr.Zero); //Write method works
        Buffer[0] = 0x01;


        bool read = DeviceIoControl(devHandle, 0xb01a2, null, 0, Buffer, (uint)Buffer.Length, ref writtenByteLength, IntPtr.Zero); //This returns false and does not work

        if (!read) {
            Global.logger.Info("Error Code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        Global.logger.Info("Read Status: " + write + ": " + read);
        Global.logger.Info("Read Bytes: " + Buffer[0] + ": " + Buffer[1]);

    }
```

Since this code works fine in C++, I have no idea why its returning error 87 which is incorrect paramters in C#. Because write method works fine using same PInvoke and I have been able to change keyboard LED colors. I have tried doing Marshal conversion from byte[] to IntPtr and passing the byte[] as IntPtr but that doesn't seem to work either. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I usually suggest doing all this work in a C++/CLI assembly and exporting some kind of .NET API to the C# program.  In principle P/Invoke usually will work with the right MarshalAs incantations, but I don't quite trust it.

Comment: There is one obvious bug, the error checking for CreateFile() is broken.  You won't notice, next DeviceIoControl() fails with 87.  Use devHandle.IsInvalid instead.

Comment: @HansPassant isInvalid returns false so I assume CreateFile() method is working as intended. Probably that's why I have no issue in writing instructions as well, only issue is with read method.